# Topology neighbourhood, example/explanation.

Tags: general-topology

Today in class we had the following def.

Let $(X,T)$ be a top. space and $x \in X$. A set $U \subset X$ is called a neighbourhood of $x$ if there is a $V \in T$ with $x \in V$ and $V \subset U$ ($V$ can be equal to $U$ i.e $V=U$).

Can someone provide a simple example of this?

Comment: Did you add "of $x$" @MichaelHoppe?

Comment: Yes. Because a topological neighborhood is a  “neighborhood of ...” .

Comment: That was embarrising, it makes a lot more sense now. Well if anyone wants to provide an example anyways, it will not hurt. :) @MichaelHoppe

Comment: There's no need to be embarrassed.  Be sure, we've all gone through this way, more or less (more more than less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any open set $V$ and any of its points. Then the open set is a neighbourhood of the point (in this case $U=V$).

Now add anything you want to the open set $V$ and you will get a set $U$ that might not be open but that will contain the open set $V$ such that $x\in V$.

The open set $V$ could be an open disk, the point $x$ its center, and $U$ the closed disk with same center and radius

Comment: $U$ can also be the entire plane or any other open disk (or set) containing $V$

Answer (score 0):

The invention of neighborhoods is due to technical and convienient reasons in proves. A point $ x$ in a topological room $X$ may live in a weird subset $U$ of $X$.  To access $x$ in its home $U$ topologically we must assure  that $x$ is contained in an open set $V$  of $X$ which lives in $U$.